# What is the best/fastest way to learn GLADE with C?

Tags: c, gtk, glade

I just downloaded and installed GLADE. What are some good tutorials for the C language?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This tutorial goes in details with examples in both C and Python: [Designing a User Interface using Glade](http://www.micahcarrick.com/12-24-2007/gtk-glade-tutorial-part-1.html)

Comment: +1 for @TStamper for the same link. His answer was added while I was editing my answer! That seems to happen a lot on SO.

Comment: @nzpcmad: Yeah, happens to me all the time.

Comment: The webpage the link is supposed to go to is hacked.... I clicked on it and got thrown into a sketchy ad.

Answer (score 3):

"Linux Today" has [A Pair of Glade Tutorials](http://www.linuxtoday.com/news_story.php3?ltsn=2001-12-10-011-20-PS-GN-HL)

Most tutorials, though, use C++ or C#.

Comment: 2nd link is dead

Answer (score 0):

I found a very good glade tutorial index here:
https://live.gnome.org/Glade/Tutorials